# can modules has their own namespaces in rest api?

Tags: rest

Our project has modules like CMS,e-commerce & ... and also has core resources that has all shared models.
our URIs is like blow:

```
/api/v1/{module-name}/{resources}
GET /api/v1/cms/posts/1
GET /api/v1/core/users/1
PUT /api/v1/cms/posts/1
```

Do this rest api uri design standard or we can use better uri design?

Answer (score 1):

There is no REST url design standard, and there is nothing really wrong with giving your urls a good namespace.